# python code to convert mail from pst to eml format

Tags: python, eml, pst

Is there any python code to convert outlook pst mails to eml format. Please also suggest for any such code in some other language. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

def convert_pst_to_mbox(pstfilename, outputfolder):
    subprocess.call(['readpst', '-o', outputfolder, '-r', pstfilename])
```

Of course, you must install [libpst utilities](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/) for that to work.

Comment: @pap, no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail#Filename_extensions, but you can convert: http://www.google.com/search?q=mbox+to+eml