# PST to EML with Python

Tags: python, eml, pst

I am looking for how to "convert" from PST to EML in Python.

Is there some way to convert a PST file to EML while keeping the formatted text and attachments?
I was not able to find it on Google.

Any help or advice, I appreciate a lot.

Thanks

Comment: check out this link - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605397/convert-pst-into-multiple-eml-files-in-python`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python code to convert mail from pst to eml format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795202/python-code-to-convert-mail-from-pst-to-eml-format)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Does it work on Windows? because for that solution I should install libpst